# sqlite3 doesnt retain rows after restart

Tags: android, sqlite

im trying to save a row in my settings table, it works all fine and dandy except when i kill the app and then try to get the row back it cant find it

```
Cursor c = db.query(savedSettings.getTableName(), null, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToLast();
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
```

here's how i do my closing:

```
public void onPause() {
    db.close();
}

public void onDestroy() {
    db.close();     
    database.close();
}

public void onStop() {
    db.close();
    database.close();
}

public void onResume() {
    db = database.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

after i restart the app it loses its contents.
Anyone got any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve data after activity restart.Consider using following code snippet.

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        Here you will write to things to bundle which you want to preserve
            after activity restart.

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Here you will restore the values.
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Please invest your time in reading

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#SavingActivityState

Hope this help.

Comment: My Data has to persist longer then the lifecycle of one instance of the app. But thx